# BCL Delegate-Based IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to have a concrete `IDisposable` that takes a delegate in its constructor, so that it executes the delegate when disposed.  I think the [AutoCleanup class](http://www.wadeware.net/software-development/c-autocleanup-class-leverage-idisposable-and-lambda-expressions-to-get-rid-of-clumsy-tryfinally-blocks/) is an example of what I'm after, but I'd like to use something defined in the BCL rather than write or borrow something to achieve this.

Does it exist somewhere in the BCL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this exists in the BCL, so you're left with the two alternatives you'd hoped to avoid: write it, or reference someone else's implementation.

Your best bet is [Disposable.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.disposable.create(v=vs.103).aspx) from the Microsoft Reactive Extensions (Rx) library. The [source code](https://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Core/Reactive/Disposables/AnonymousDisposable.cs) is actually very simple, so you could write your own version in just a few lines, or import the [Rx-Core](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Core/) nuget package.